# How to git add changed files to a buried commit (not the lastest commit)

Tags: git

Say I have file `A.txt`,`B.txt`,`C.txt`,`D.txt`,`E.txt`. Now I made changes to `A.txt` and `B.txt`, and make commit `c1`. And then I edit `C.txt`, and make commit `c2`. Similarly, I edit `D.txt` and `E.txt`, and make commit `c3`. So now the git log, from latest to older one, is `c3` -> `c2` -> `c1`.

And then I edit `A.txt`, and want to add these new changes to `A.txt` to commit `c1`. And I also want to keep `c2` and `c3` untouched, and keep the `c3` -> `c2` -> `c1` ordering in git log.

Now what I'm doing is just `git reset c1 --soft`, `git add A.txt`, and then `git commit --amend --no-edit`. In this example there're just 3 files involved in the following `c2` and `c3`, so `git reset` is not that painful. But when there're 20+ files involved in `c2` and `c3`, it will be very time-consuming to go over everything again.

So is there any way other than `git reset --soft` to do that?

Comment: Install SmartGit, and you can easily modify any commit you want. It's done via a rebase, so you can also learn (by viewing the command output pane) how it does it :)

Comment: Look into using the `--fixup` switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with fixup commits.  Here's how the approach works:

1. Add the files you want to modify with `git add`.
2. Run `git commit --fixup c1`.  If you want to modify the commit message for c1, run `git commit --squash c1` instead, and you'll be prompted for additional text to add to the commit message.
3. Run `git rebase -i --autosquash c1^`.  If c1 is the root commit, run `git rebase -i --autosquash --root` instead.  This will open an editor showing you each of the commits, and which ones will be squashed into each other.  You can just save and quit since you used `--autosquash`.
4. If you used `--squash` above, you'll be prompted to combine the two commit messages into a single one for your commit, so do that, save, and quit.

This will result in you adding the files to c1 without changing the contents of c2 and c3.  The IDs of c2 and c3 will change, since each commit depends on the previous commit, but the changes each introduces will not.

The way this works is that in step 2, you're creating what are called fixup or squash commits (depending on the option).  These are written with a special first line of the commit message, so when you use `git rebase -i --autosquash`, Git knows which commit to coalesce them into.  The `--autosquash` option tells Git to reorder these commits for you so you don't have to.

If you really don't want to be prompted to edit the TODO list from `git rebase -i`, you can precede the command with `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=true` (in a POSIX sh), and it will avoid you being prompted.

Note that it is possible that you may run into conflicts by doing this, which is going to be unavoidable in some circumstances.  You'll just have to resolve the conflicts and continue the rebase, and Git will prompt you which commands to use.

Comment: Good looks! Just a note for those other Git beginners out there (like myself)... `c1^` means "the parent of c1" [Git Reference](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection). So make sure you rebase to the parent of c1, otherwise your fix up will not work.